# How can I do a redirect from the backend Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have an application served with React Js for the frontend and Django for the backend. Upon sending some informations to the server, I would like to make a redirect that would occur on the frontend, is it possible ? If so how ?
I tried redirecting but it didn't work

The front-end (reactJs)

```
async function PaymentHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    const data = { command_id: order._id, price: order.TotalPrice };

    try {
     
      const res = await axios.post("/api/orders/Details/", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("THERES AN ERROR : ", error);
    }
  }
  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
  ) : (
    <div>
      
        <Button
        variant="outline-primary"
        className="mt-3"
        onClick={PaymentHandler}
        >
            PAY NOW
        </Button>
    </div>
    )
```

Model.py

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    paymentDetails = models.JSONField()
```

Model serializer

```
class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
paymentDetails = serializers.JSONField()
class Meta:
    model = Stuff
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from base.models import Stuff
from base.serializers import PaymentSerializer
import requests
import json


@api_view(['POST'])
def getPaymentDetails(request):
    data = request.data
    payment = Stuff.objects.create(
        paymentDetails = data
    )
    serializer = PaymentSerializer(payment, many=False)
    last = Stuff.objects.last()
   
    details = (last.paymentDetails)
    print('cmd id value :', details['command_id'])
    print('price id value :', details['price'])

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0exxxxxxxxxxxx"}
    url = "https://apps.somewebsite.com/"
    payload = {"payment_data":{
        "command_id":details['command_id'],
        "price":details['price']},
        "data":{"return_url":"some return url",
        "cancel_url":"some cancel url",
        "shop_code":1}}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    print('request result : ', r.text)
    result = r.text
    result=json.loads(result)
 
    if result['status'] == 1:
        print ('payment token = ', result['payment_token'])
        
        return redirect('https://welcome.somewebsite.com/payment/'+result['payment_token'])
```

Comment: Ummm Yes Django can do this, but its you need to add the url to your urls.py file and name it. Then you can redirect it thru the url file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();    
const res = await axios.post("/api/orders/Details/", data)
    .then(res=>{
           // if status is OK, 200 or 201 redirect with react
           history.push("/your_success_path");
        })
    .catch(err => {
        //update error state 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to redirect to your index page from `getPaymentDetails()`

You need to register an url in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView, name='index'),
]
```

Then, you can redirect from your function like this.

```
def getPaymentDetails(request):
...
    return redirect('index')
```